# What font is used on this keyboard?

Tags: typography

[image: Acer ChromeBook 11 C732 C733]

I need to identify the font that is printed on this keyboard. It's an Acer Chromebook 11 C723 & 733

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be Noto Sans from Google, which is even free. All the distinctive character details look the same. (shape of the a, g, t, y, number of points on *, shape of @, shape of the 1 and 7, etc) The % sign might have been squashed a bit, though.

It's not Google's related Droid Sans or Open Sans typefaces, which have a two-story g.